# What is the name of the OST?

Tags: music, jojos-bizarre-adventure

[On this Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qv7u65z8cj0&t=84s), part 1;28, there's a trumpet start to play and I already find quite a while still can't find what song is that. Anyone know that song?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's [Uru - Freesia](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=loxujxwIb5U). The part you want starts at around 1:20

Edit: The [orchestra version](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d81DH5veOe0) used in the video